# Filter the same sheet in every excel file using nested for loop

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, pandas.excelwriter

Below is the code which I have written to filter 'Freshness' sheet in every excel files present inside the folder. But whenever I open each excel file all the data inside each excel file is already been deleted by the code. Please suggest any other way of doing the same operation

**Dataset:-**

[Dataset Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZgQdl.png)

**Code:-**

```
df_sold_to_list = pd.ExcelFile('C:/Users/ISLAMS/Downloads/Adhoc/Automation/VMI Scorecard/APS/All Sold to list.xlsx')
df_aps = pd.read_excel(df_sold_to_list, 'APS')

files_path = 'C:/Users/ISLAMS/Downloads/Adhoc/Automation/VMI Scorecard/APS/'
read_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(files_path,"*.xlsx"))

for files in read_files:
    for i in range(len(df_aps)):
        row_item = df_aps.loc[i, 'Sold To']
        df = pd.ExcelFile(files)
        df_freshness = pd.read_excel(df, 'Freshness')
        df_freshness.loc[df_freshness['Sold To'] == row_item]
        break
```

Comment: kindly share a sample data of one of the sheets - makes it easier to understand ur code, and possibly write a function to apply to all the sheets

Comment: @sammywemmy Added a screenshot for your reference